# Why only left speaker is working?

Tags: audio, speakers

I am working on Debian Stable Linux with attached 2 external speakers. Both are working when I play media files with `vlc` software.

However, with following command, I am getting sound from only one speaker. In output of following command, it only gives `Front left` and no other:

```
$ speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -l 2 2>&1

speaker-test 1.2.4

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Sine wave rate is 1000.0000Hz
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 192 to 2097152
Period size range from 64 to 699051
Using max buffer size 2097152
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 524288
was set buffer_size = 2097152
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10.954092
 0 - Front Left
Time per period = 10.953519
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man 1 speaker-test`:

> `-c | --channels NUM`
> `NUM` channels in stream

Your command created a stream with parameters `48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels`. Apparently the default value for `-c` is `1`. Use `-c 2` to test two channels:

```
speaker-test -t sine -f 1000 -c 2 -l 2
```

Comment: Yes, this command shows both speakers. Thanks.